# trying to convert double presision number to decimal

Tags: java, double-precision

I'm trying to convert double precision number to decimal . 
 for example the number 22 in double precision and as bytes are :

```
[0] 0
[1] 0
[2] 0
[3] 0
[4] 0
[5] 0
[6] 54
[7] 64
```

now I try to convert these values again to 22  :

```
  ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
  long l = buffer.getLong();
  long b = Double.doubleToLongBits(l);
```

but the result is something totally wrong :`4.6688606E18`
what's this number ? please help , I'm totally confused!

according to IEEE Standard 754 for double precision:

Any value stored as a double requires 64 bits, formatted as shown in the table below:

63
Sign (0 = positive, 1 = negative)

62 to 52
Exponent, biased by 1023

51 to 0
Fraction f of the number 1.f

now how should I convert double precision to numbers to get 22 again ? all of these answers are wrong

Comment: That is 4.67 * 10 to the 18th power.

Comment: but it's totally nonsence ! where is 22 then :((

Comment: You need to be more specific as to exactly what you want to convert. Can you give us a complete example showing what you want to do?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. And a double is 64 bits long (8 bytes), so I really don't understand your question. If you have a double and you want a long just do `long l = (long) d`.

Comment: You have the binary representation of your double in l, converting it with doubleToLongBits will wrongly interpret l as a normal long value (instead of the double value it holds)

Comment: it's actually 64 bits, 16*4 = 64  but how can we correctly convert double precision to long ? it should give me 22 again

Comment: @melisazand: one byte = 8 bits. 64 bits = 8 bytes.

Comment: you're right I corrected that

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure *exactly* what sort of conversion you're trying to do (when you say "convert to decimal", what is your desired output format/class?)

However, my first thought reading the title was that a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) would be a valid representation.  So the first approach would be to do something like the following:

```
double d = ...; // your input number
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(d);
```

That said, if you want to convert to decimal then it's presumably because there are floating ponit/rounding issues with the value of `d`, which will still be present in the `BigDecimal` representation as it's being constructed based on `d`.

The best approach to get around this is to use `BigDecimals` from the get-go, using their `String` constructor - so there won't be any instances of floating-point rounding.  If this isn't an option for whatever reason, you can convert the `double` to a string in such a way that it will account for many floating point rounding issues:

```
String strRep = Double.toString(d);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(strRep);
```

Comment: Was going to point out `String` as a way to keep precision but you beat me to it! Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can write simple test (with JUnit):

```
double initial = 22.0;

long bits = Double.doubleToLongBits(initial);

double converted = Double.longBitsToDouble(bits);

assertEquals(Double.valueOf(initial), Double.valueOf(converted));
```

If this works - check you have correct byte representation for 22 (correct representation will be at bits variable).